# How to insert a page break manually in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, page-break

In my project, an **Article** has many **Items** within it. Since each Item has different length, so I would like to implement pagination manually, for example, by creating a **PageBreakItem** model, in order to allow users insert page breaks wherever they want. But I don't know how to use "page" parameter in controller to render views correctly.

Some gems like kaminari or will_paginate only allow me to configure the number of items per page. They don't have options for inserting page breaks manually.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a special model for this. You could do this with small adaptation of your `Item` model:
Add `sort_order` numeric field to denote order of items within the article and `is_on_new_page` boolean field to denote a page break occurring before that article.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
Actually, I use [Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) technique in my project. There are some types of Items that are inherited from the original Item model, such as HeadingItem, TextItem, ImageItem... So it would be easier to create a new PageBreakItem model in my case. 
Anyway, the idea of `sort_order` field is really nice. I guess I can implement the controller now.

Comment: I implemented my controller successfully! Thank you very much!